# While loop with condition from sql

Tags: sql

> Keep dividing a column X by 10 until it is less than the Y*0.15 then do a final step of *10.

How to achieve this. I did this C# with while loop have to do same in SQL.

while (Y*0.15 < X)
X = X / 10
return X*10

Comment: while (Y*0.15 < X)
{
                X = X / 10
}return X*10

Comment: Do you actually need a while loop? Sounds like a math problem. Derive the value for z from x / (10 ^ z) = y * .15, and the final answer is x / (10 ^ floor(z)). You'll have to correct for exact z of course.

Comment: Please [edit] your post instead of writing code in the comments.

Comment: I Couldnt get it  - Yuriy Faktorovich

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @y float,
@x float,
@i int = 1

select @x = columnName, @y = columnName  from TableName where condition

while (@y*0.15 < @x) 
Begin
    print(@i)
    set @x = @x / 10 
    set @i = @i+1 
END
select @x*10
```

Comment: how to take @y @x from SQL instead of declare static value. Also what is the use of @i here

Comment: while (X*0.15 < Y)
                Y= Y / 10;
            return Y*10;
Help this in SQL please

Comment: updated answer and @i is a count of how many times loop run